# dplyr: group_by usando un vector de texto como argumento

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Tenemos un data frame que queremos agrupar usando la función `group_by` del paquete `dplyr`, pero los nombres de las columnas que deseamos agrupar se encuentran en un vector de texto (un caso de uso: el vector es resultado de otra función).

Como ejemplo, el conjunto `mpg` de `data()`.

```r
library(dplyr)
```

```r
head(mpg)

  manufacturer model displ year cyl      trans drv cty hwy fl   class
1         audi    a4   1.8 1999   4   auto(l5)   f  18  29  p compact
2         audi    a4   1.8 1999   4 manual(m5)   f  21  29  p compact
3         audi    a4   2.0 2008   4 manual(m6)   f  20  31  p compact
4         audi    a4   2.0 2008   4   auto(av)   f  21  30  p compact
5         audi    a4   2.8 1999   6   auto(l5)   f  16  26  p compact
6         audi    a4   2.8 1999   6 manual(m5)   f  18  26  p compact
```

Agrupamos por manufacturer y model y el resultado es el siguiente, 38 grupos.

```r
group_by(mpg, manufacturer, model)

# A tibble: 234 x 11
# Groups:   manufacturer, model [38]

[etc...]
```

Pero si usamos el vector `c("manufacturer", "model")` el resultado es un error.

```r
group_by(mpg, c("manufacturer", "model"))

Error: Problem adding computed columns in `group_by()`.
x Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
i `..1 = c("manufacturer", "model")`.
i `..1` must be size 234 or 1, not 2.
```

Es posible dar "manufacturer" y "model" como dos argumentos, sin ser parte de un mismo vector, pero entonces no ocurre la agrupación esperada.

```r
group_by(mpg, "manufacturer", "model")

# A tibble: 234 x 13
# Groups:   "manufacturer", "model" [1]

[etc...]
```

Una opción es usar `group_by_(mpg, c("manufacturer", "model"))`, pero `group_by_()` es considerada obsoleta desde `dplyr` 0.7.0 (al igual que otras funciones similares, como `mutate_()`).

¿Qué alternativas existen para lograr esta agrupación con estas características usando `dplyr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo esta solución que funciona perfectamente,

```
mpg %>% 
  group_by(across(c("manufacturer", "model")))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
mpg %>% 
  group_by(!!!c("manufacturer", "model"))
```

Usando los tres signos de admiración `!!!` para abrir la cadena de caracteres e inyectarlos en la función como nombres en el argumento `...`

El problema es que `dplyr` hace un tipo de evaluación no estándar para poder recibir nombre de columnas (que al fin y al cabo son cadenas de caracteres) como nombre (sin comillas). Antes estaban las funciones terminadas en `_` pero por algún motivo las quitaron y ahora hay que estar probando para ver si acertamos con `{{}}`, `!!`, `!!!`, `enquo(x)` y así.